# Scala object import from another script loaded using Java ScriptEngine gives an error

Tags: java, scala, scriptengine

I have a Scala object like below

```
object Loader{
  //Implementation
}
```

Then I have another Scala script which is loaded by a Java application using ScriptEngine.

```
import Loader

class Activity {
  //Implementation
} 

new Activity()
```

I use below code to get a compiled script of above class.

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("scala");

FileReader fr = new FileReader(file)
compilable = (Compilable)engine
compiledScript = compilable.compile(fr);
```

When I do the above I get following error.

> . expected in [code of Activity class]

Is there a way I can make the import mentioned above?

Comment: As far as the error goes, are you sure this is actually import problem and not a syntax error (as it looks to me)?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes. Without the import the code works without an issue.

Comment: What do you mean works without an issue? The syntax looks very strange to me. Seems like it would be really hard to tell what is wrong without actually being in your idé. The Activity class sounds like something that's not related to Scala. But maybe @M.Prokhorov has a point. Maybe your Scala syntax is off, causing the Java application to not load. I've used .asInstanceOf[Class] before. So maybe try that? Sorry but it seems hard to know from the info you given

Comment: @GamingFelix I edited a part I missed. Hope now you get it. I get an object of the Activity class and call the functions in that class from the Java code. The name "Activity" is just a name given. The code works as it is without the import. I want to add some new functionality that would be only used within the script.

Comment: @Will_Panda, do you mean "without import only" or "without all code that refers to the `Loader`"? Because your error looks like a syntax error. Although, what package the `Loader` is in? Is that import correct? Will it work from REPL?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  "without all code that refers to the Loader". Sorry if there was any confusion. If I comment all the code that refers "Loader" and just keep the import even then I get the mentioned error. Loader is in the same package as Activity.

Comment: @Will_Panda, maybe it's a classpath issue then? See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130824/script-engine-giving-error-when-evaluating-scala-script-in-java) has any useful clues.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to run scala as a script? It is possible to compile the scala code and use it in Java via classpath, no? You should include the scala runtime jars in the classpath though

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I assumed so too. Is there a way to give additional classpaths to ScriptEngine? I tried giving the classpath to the application but it didn't work.

Comment: @Genry it is possible. But the decision was made due to some packaging issues.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov the solution in the question you mentioned worked for me. I added -Dscala.usejavacp=true as a JVM option and added the compiled Loader file's path to jvm classpath. One more question. Is there a way this could be done at runtime. Like using the Script engine to compile Loader class so the Activity class can pick it up. Thank you.

Comment: @Will_Panda, or so if it was indeed a classpath problem try changing `settings().classpath()` property if `IMain` instead of `usejavacp()`. That should set the classpath for the script engine specifically, without the need for you to alter the general app classpath. Something like [that](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/using-scala-as-a-java-scriptengine/4524) should work (obviously, with your path rather than what's in snippets). For all settings, you can crawl starting from [here](https://github.com/scala/legacy-svn-scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/MutableSettings.scala)

Comment: @Will_Panda, in that last link, look closely that `MutableSettings` extends `ScalaSettings`, and that one has the `classpath()` property, which is-a `PathSetting`, that should support `append()` and `prepend()`. The above links are from legacy version, but it looks pretty much the same in [this modern branch](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thank you for the info. I'll use this instead of giving a vm option during startup for the current work around. But the preferred solution is to use CompiledScript to compile the Loader script as well. If there's a way to do that I can escape compiling the Loader script before application startup. I couldn't find a proper answer for that anywhere.

Comment: @Will_Panda, I'm not sure then. If compiled script is saved somewhere in a file, it's simply a case of adding that file to classpath. If not, you could try binding the loader as an object into the script, that should also do the trick, but then you don't need any imports.